# Behavior of this.submit() inside form submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
        var formElement = document.querySelector('form');
        formElement.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('addEventListener event handler');
            this.submit(); // not causing recursive call.
        }, false)
    </script>
```

Why isn't going as recursive event handling. I thought this.submit() will call the function/event handler (under which it exists) again. I don't face any issue with this , but just want to know how it is working and not as a recursive call.

Comment: Should it be `formElement.submit();` instead of `this.submit()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling .submit on the form itself doesn't trigger an event, it just submits the form. therefore, the event handler doesn't get executed because there is no event.

Comment: Thanks. this.submit() -> calling submit on form is an event right? Or kind of doing action right. so it should fire the action/event right?

Comment: It's an action, but it does not trigger the event.